# Determine what hard drive a file or directory is on?

Tags: macos, bash, unix

Using the command line on a mac, given a file or directory, I would like to find out the best way to determine what physical hard drive the file or directory lives on.

My googling and stackoverflow searching hasn't helped me so far.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux you can use the `df` utility. I don't know if it exists on mac.

```
df filename
```

Comment: Yes, it's on a mac too.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How about using `mount`?

```
mount | grep '^/dev/' | sed -E 's/([^ ]*) on ([^ ]*) .*/"\2" is located on "\1"/'
```

*bmk* also had a nice idea: use `df`. Here's how you could use it in a shell script:

```
df XXX | grep '/dev' | sed -E 's/([^ ]*).*/\1/'
```

Replace XXX with any path of your choice. You could use it like this in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
device=`df $1 | grep '/dev' | sed -E 's/([^ ]*).*/\1/'`
echo $1 resists on device $device
```

Store it as "mountpoint.sh", make it executable, and call it with `./mountpoint.sh <file>`

Credits (and upvotes) go to bmk :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used a mac but on a Gnu/Linux machine, I suppose you could find the complete path of the file using `readlink` and then look through the output of `mount` to find on which mountpoint (and therefore partition and physical drive) it is on.

Comment: The hard part being the "then look through the output of `mount`" part. (On Linux, it's even easier with the `mountpoint` command, but I can't find that in any online Mac OS X manual.)